# ajax POST on form sumbit event not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

i have problem with ajax post with form submit event. i have table generated by opentable.php

here code for opentable.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require("dbc.php");
$memberid = $_SESSION['memberid'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `open` WHERE `memberid`='$memberid'";
$mydata = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table><tr><th>Time</th><th>Type</th><th>Size</th><th>Price</th><th>Profit</th><th></th><th></th></tr>";
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){
    echo "<form action = assets/close.php id=closeform>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['opendate'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['type'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['size'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['openprice'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['profit'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>"."<input type=hidden name=openid value=".$record['openid']." </td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=close value=close". " </td>";
    //echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";
    }
echo "</table>";


?>
```

and ajax javasript for submit event trade.js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#closeform').submit(function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $form = $( this ),
            price = $('#price').val(),
            id = $form.find( "input[name='openid']" ).val(),
            url = $form.attr( "action" );
            var posting = $.post( url, { openid: id, closeprice: price } );
            var r=confirm("Are you sure?");
            if(r =true){
                posting.done(function( data ) {
                    alert(data);
                    });
                }
            else
              {
              alert("Transaction canceled")
              }

        });
}
```

i tested it, and it runs like normal php form. and error there is no $_POST data passed.
please give me recomendation for this kind of event thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`closeform` is a dynamically added form, try using `.on()`:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#closeform', function ( event ) {
```

Comment: the event fixed but why value of post openid and closeprice undifined on close php.

Comment: @user2698904 -- Make sure the values are defined when sending it over, and retrieve them with `$_POST['dataKeyName']`

Comment: <?php
session_start();
require("dbc.php");
$memberid = $_SESSION['memberid'];
$openid= $_POST['openid'];
$closeprice= $_POST['closeprice'];?>

Comment: @user2698904 -- Check your console, is the request going thru?

Comment: i test alert id, it was undefined. it someting wrong with my declaration?

Comment: @user2698904 -- Not that I see...try giving an ID to your input and grab it that way.

Comment: i tried give id but only giving first record, another record give same id as first record i declare id =$(#openid).val